# Are tasks in gulp run in sequences?

Tags: gulp

Basic question but i just cannot find answer yet.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('one', function(cb) {
  // do stuff -- async or otherwise
  cb(err); 
});

gulp.task('two', function(cb) {
  // do something
  cb(err)
});

gulp.task('three', function(cb) {
  // do something
  cb(err)
});
```

The Q is: does task 2 only runs when task 1 finishes, task 3 only runs when task 2 finishes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just this setup, only one task will be executed at all, e.g. task `two` if you invoke `gulp two`.

You can create composite tasks with the help of the functions `series(...)` and `parallel(...)` provided by Gulp. The new task will run the tasks passed to the function either in sequence or in parallel. Calls to the functions can be nested to create more complex scenarios.